# Mover los contenedores para dejar el nav arriba junto con el logo principal

Tags: css

El problema es que no puedo bajar las container box y subir el nav, llevo horas y aun no logro arreglarlo.

```
<body>
    <div align="center">
        <img class="logo" src="pics/logo.jpg" width="300" height="300"/>
    </div>

    <div class="nav">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="item-options">Inicio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="item-options">Hace tu pedido</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="item-options">¿ Quienes Somos ?</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="item-options">Contactos</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="card pollo">
            <img src="pics/alas.PNG" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="informacion">
            <h1>Porcion de alitas de pollo chica + papas fritas</h1>
            <p class="stock">Disponible</p>
        </div>
        <div class="precio">
            <div class="box-precio">
                <span class="precio1"><strike>CLP/6999</strike></span>
                <span class="precio2">CLP4999</span>
            </div>
                <span class="shoping"><i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <div class="card pollo">
            <img src="pics/alas.PNG" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="informacion">
            <h1>Porcion de alitas de pollo chica + papas fritas</h1>
            <p class="stock">Disponible</p>
        </div>
        <div class="precio">
            <div class="box-precio">
                <span class="precio1"><strike>CLP/6999</strike></span>
                <span class="precio2">CLP4999</span>
            </div>
                <span class="shoping"><i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <div class="card pollo">
            <img src="pics/alas.PNG" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="informacion">
            <h1>Porcion de alitas de pollo chica + papas fritas</h1>
            <p class="stock">Disponible</p>
        </div>
        <div class="precio">
            <div class="box-precio">
                <span class="precio1"><strike>CLP/6999</strike></span>
                <span class="precio2">CLP4999</span>
                </div>
                    <span class="shoping"><i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i></span>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Si añades los estilos quizás se puede ver la causa. Por cierto esto no parece correcto <div align="center">, align no es atributo de div, ¿será style o class?

Answer (score 0):

Si lo he entendido bien, quieres poner el menú de navegación al lado del logotipo.

Para ello puedes usar "float", tal y como te indico:

Añadir clase al div del logo

```
<body>
    <div align="center" class="div-logo">
        <img class="logo" src="pics/logo.jpg" width="300" height="300"/>
    </div>
```

Usar estos estilos

```
.div-logo { float: left; }
.nav { float: left; }
.content { clear: both; }
```

Luego "limpias" para que el resto te quede debajo.

Mira a ver si es lo que necesistas.